# When was it first confirmed in canon that the wars that nearly destroyed the Vulcans was fought using high technology weapons?

Tags: star-trek

In the original series (TOS) of Star Trek the audience is told that the Vulcans fought a series of devastating wars that almost destroyed their species, before embracing logic and pacifism.

Very little information is provided on the nature of these wars in the TOS, what information that the audience is given comes in the form of verbal descriptions of there being wars, but not of how the wars were fought.

Further information is given in the Next Generation and other subsequent TV series, but with very little detail before the war itself is shown in Enterprise season 4. At which time it is confirmed that the war was fought with high technology weapons and was analogous to a nuclear war with mushroom clouds being shown on screen and descriptions being given of weapons of mass destruction being used.

Was this first time in canonical material that the war was confirmed to have been a high technology war - as opposed to a war fought using primitive weapons such as bows and arrows or black powder weapons - if not which episode, canonical book\video game\other media is it first confirmed?

Comment: In TNG they show a powerful psionic weapon capable of killing people and ships

Comment: @Valorum, do you know which episode this was?

Comment: Gambits Part I and II. We see the resonator in action in part II, https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Psionic_resonator